# Which version of arm gnu toolchain should I use to run on Rpi 4B?

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, arm, embedded, gnu

I want to use Raspberry Pi 4B to compile code for stm32. Therefore I download the "AArch64 Linux hosted cross toolchains" version of arm-none-eabi from this [website](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads). Then I `scp` to Rpi and unzip it.

But I cannot execute it. The shell told me that `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. Did I download the worng version?

The architecture of Rpi is "armv7l" and the OS I'm using is Pi OS(buster). I thought it belongs to "AArch64 Linux hosted".

Thank you ~

Answer (score 1):

That is ARM v7 architecture.
IIRC, the raspi hardware is armv8 capable machines, but RPI OS runs in aarch32 mode, which is compatibility mode for armv7.
You can also check cpuinfo to be sure about it.

On an ARMv7 kernel/OS(aarch32), armv8 applications cannot be run, but on armv8(aarch64) kernel/OS armv7 applications can be run in aarch32 mode.
Refer [ARM's Learn the architecture: Aarch64 Exception Model](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102412/0102/Execution-and-Security-states?lang=en) for more details.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 108.00
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 108.00
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining!! Does this mean I should find a compiler version for "aarch32" plattform?

Comment: @Benycu: Yes, correct.

Comment: Is it possible that I build from source? It seems Arm doesn't provide one for aarch32 plattform!

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads) for aarch32 toolchains, see if the linux one works on raspi.

If it doesn't work, probably check if stm32 provides raspbian hosted cross toolchain.
My educated guess is they don't, as not many users exists who want to compile code on embedded platform and run it on another.

Only as a last resort, try to build the compiler toolchain on raspi for stm32.
Instead see if you can get away by building it on Linux/Windows/MacOS box. It will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

the stm is either armv6-m, arv7-m or one of the armv8-ms.  The pi itself is armv8.  You either need to run the pi in 32 bit aarch32 mode and use a native compiler or use a cross compiler.   aarch64 is armv8-a (arm 64 bit, the armv7-a is the aarch32 compatibility mode).

So you will want to get arm-none-eabi, which you claim but you also claimed aarch64 if it were aarch64 then it would be aarch64-none-eabi or some such name.

Like any other computer you can just get or build for (not hard to build gnu toolchain from sources) arm (32 bit) and get the one that can build for stm32.

gcc version 3.x.x to the present, technically, can build code that will run on an stm32.

If you plan to use a C library then even though you can use the native toolchain on an armv7 based linux on the pi, it is arm-whatever-linux-gnueabi not arm-whatever-eabi and may not work for you.

Just get arm-none-eabi based toolchain, use the proper command line options, and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question~ But what I meant by '"AArch64 Linux hosted cross toolchains" version' is that this cross compiler are designed to run on a AArch64 Linux computer. I want to first compile my program on Rpi then flash into stm32 from Rpi.

Comment: So what you say is that I can just use the normal g++ on Rpi to compile my code, then flash that executable into stm32?

Comment: It seems that I cannot download the lastest arm gnu toolchain using command line(Arm says we need to download from their website). So if there is no aarch32 host version, the only option I have is to build from source right?

Comment: or any of the many other places you can download pre-built binaries.   no reason to download it from arm.  did you try sudo apt-get -y install gcc-arm-none-eabi binutils-arm-none-eabi
?

Comment: ahhhh, you are trying to execute this binary on the pi?   Are you trying to build binaries for stm32 or are you trying to build linux binaries for your linux computer?   if the linux computer then just use the native tools, done.  If stm32 then you cannot execute those on the pi

Comment: I'm trying to build the code for stm32. I want to build it on Rpi then flash to stm32 and execute it on stm32. I read an announcment from Arm before said that they will not update the toolchain on apt.

Comment: arm is arm, gnu is gnu.  If you want to go and find arm blessed builds then that is not a stackoverflow question

Comment: the apt gettable ones for the last number of years will build programs for your stm32.

Comment: where is this exec format error message coming from?

Comment: The error message is coming from Rpi when I'm trying to execute the cross compiler.